# Generating Dates between two date ranges in AWK

Tags: date, awk, intervals

I need to create a list of days between a date interval.
Say for example from 2001-01-01 to 2009-12-31:

```
2001-01-01
2001-01-02
2001-01-03
..
2009-12-29
2009-12-30
2009-12-31
```

I know how to do it but maybe someone has a script already made?
If not, I will make such a script and upload it so others won't waste time on this when they need it.

Comment: Related: [bash loop between two given dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629015/bash-loop-between-two-given-dates)

Comment: Well, the main purpose of SO is rather to help others solve things they've alrady tried but could not solve by themselves. If you want to post something useful, you should either come up with a problem out of it, for others/you to solve; or simply create a blog for yourself.

Comment: read your `date` man page. I would specifically look for the `-d` option.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a real question.

Comment: Cant't use bash because I work in Windows 7. But I can use AWK from GnuWin32. I'm quite sure there are other people who need such a script so I think it's good to allow this question to exist here. If "bash loop between two given dates" is allowed then "AWK loop between two given dates" should be allowed too, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know awk from GnuWin32, but if the functions "mktime" and "strftime" are available, you can try the following code:

```
BEGIN {
  START_DATE="2001-02-01"
  END_DATE="2001-03-05"

  S2=START_DATE
  gsub("-"," ",S2)

  T=mktime(S2 " 01 00 00")
  if   (T<0)
     printf("%s is invalid.\n",START_DATE) >> "/dev/stderr"
  else
  {
     for(S=START_DATE; END_DATE>S ;T+=86440) print S=strftime("%F",T)
  }
}
```

The key is to convert the start date to a number meaning the seconds since the Epoch, add 86400 seconds (one day or 24 x 60 x 60) and convert back to the ISO date format.

After some trials I realized the mktime() function admits wrong dates as good (for instance, 2000-14-03).

Best regards

Comment: Thanks, it works nice! I addeed the "BEGIN {}". Run the script in Windows with the following line: "gawk -f generate-days.awk generate-days.awk > days.txt"

Comment: @Jdamian, mktime() does NOT admits wrong dates! https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html

Comment: @agripp, I tested `print mktime("2000 14 03 00 00 00")`in a CentOS 6.5 and no error message is reported

Comment: @Jdamian, ok, the documentation is not well clear and I have expressed myself wrong. When the value for a month, for example, is -1 or 13, it means one month before or later. `print mktime("2000 14 03 00 00 00")` == `print mktime("2001 02 03 00 00 00")`